# Buildx includes headers on Docker image

Tags: docker, header, production-environment, docker-buildkit, buildx

I couldn't see a duplicate discussion topic on this so I wanted to start it.

Buildx plugin for Docker (which is built on stable Moby Buildkit tool) allows us to build for e.g. arm32/64 Docker images on x64 architecture meanwhile supposedly adding some "headers" on the Docker image according to some information on the net. Is there anyone who has information on these headers and is it safe/logical to use these cross-built images on production environments? We don't observe any performance difference when we deploy these images on our test environment but would like to know what kind of troubles these "headers" might cause us in the future if we deploy them in production.